# Refer specific row on click of button in table data fetched from JSON using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I am learning AJAX and not able to find how to refer a particular row in a table which is fetched from a .json file. Actually I want the respective data on click of the respective edit button in the row. It should be displayed in the `<p>` tag just below the table.

Heres my script

```
<script>

    function myFunction()  //on click function to fetch data from json
    {
      var counter;
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          mydata(data);

        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "employee.json");
      xhttp.send();
      counter ++ ;
    }


    function mydata(data){   //data to be shown and fetch

      var output = "<table>";
      var output = "<th>Employee Code</th>" +
                    "<th>Name</th>" +
                    "<th>Joining Date</th>" +
                    "<th>Salary</th>"+
                    "<th>Edit</th>";

            //var i in each items[i]
            for(var i in data)
            {
                output += '<tr>' + 
                '<td>' + data[i].empcode + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>'  +
                '<td>' + data[i].joining + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + data[i].salary + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + '<button onclick="edit()">Edit</button>' +
                '</tr>';
            }
            output +="</th>" + "</th>" + "</th>" + "</th>" + "</th>";
            output += "</table>";
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = output;
            function edit(){
              document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = data[1].empcode;
            }
    }





    function edit(){  //edit function to display related data from json file. Right now i  can only display data which i mentioned in editTextData().

      var edit = new XMLHttpRequest();
      edit.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(edit.readyState == 4 && edit.status == 200){
          var editData = JSON.parse(edit.responseText);
          editTextData(editData);

        }
      };
      edit.open("GET", "employee.json", true);
      edit.send();

    }

    function editTextData(textData){
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = textData[2].empcode;
    }


  </script>
```

This is the JSON data :

```
 [{
    "empcode" : 1,
    "name": "sid",
    "joining" : "13 march",
    "salary" : 60000 
    },
    {
   "empcode" : 2,
    "name": "andrew",
    "joining" : "15 march",
    "salary" : 65000  
    },
    {
    "empcode" : 3,
    "name": "blake",
    "joining" : "18 march",
    "salary" : 70000 
    }

]
```

This is the html code :

```
    <h1>AJAX Employee</h1>
  <div>
  <table id="demo"> </table>

  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" ">Fetch Info</button>
  <p id="para"> </p>
```

This is the result i am getting 
[Result table after clicking fetch button. When i click any edit button it shows the 3rd employee number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4v8f.png)

Comment: when you run this what happens?

Comment: You're overriding the table tag with the header data when assigning data to `output`. Use `+=` here too, and omit the extra `var` (it's not affecting to the results, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `edit` handler can figure out which button was clicked, which row it belongs to, and which empcode that was.  The key is the `this` value that gets passed into the edit handler.

You're assigning the handler inline, which isn't ideal, so you will need to make a change to that part:

```
'<td>' + '<button onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button>'
```

Now the button is being passed into edit as the first parameter, so:

```
function edit(btn) {  //edit function to display related data from json file. 

  // get the TR that this button is in
  var tr = btn.parentNode.parentNode;

  // get the collection of tds
  var tds = tr.querySelectorAll("td");

  // get the contents of the first TD, that should be the empcode
  var empcode = tds[0].innerText;

  // do whatever you need to with empcode, or the other values in this record
  console.log("empcode = " + empcode + ", name = " + tds[1].innerText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was very easy to understand.